# Univocity Parsers - The code doesn't run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: parsing, csv

I want to parse .csv files and I'm following the Univocity Parsers tutorial, and have added their jar file to the dependencies [here](http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/1.5.6/univocity-parsers-1.5.6.jar).

A null pointer exception occurs.

I would like to get Univocity Parsers working so I can see how good it is, here is the code I am running in IntelliJ, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.List;


public class UnivocityParsers {

public Reader getReader(String relativePath) {
    try {
        return new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath), "Windows-1252");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to read input", e);
    }
}

public void parseCSV(){

    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    //the file used in the example uses '\n' as the line separator sequence.
    //the line separator sequence is defined here to ensure systems such as MacOS and Windows
    //are able to process this file correctly (MacOS uses '\r'; and Windows uses '\r\n').
    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\r");

    // creates a CSV parser
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    // parses all rows in one go.
    List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(getReader("prodlist.csv"));

}

public static void main(String arg[]) {

    UnivocityParsers univocityParsers = new UnivocityParsers();

    univocityParsers.parseCSV();


}


}
```

Stack trace:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   
 at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:97)
 at UnivocityParsers.getReader(UnivocityParsers.java:15)
 at UnivocityParsers.parseCSV(UnivocityParsers.java:33)
 at UnivocityParsers.main(UnivocityParsers.java:41)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies in this case.  Also, please repair the formatting of the code you did post.

Comment: include your stacktrace

Comment: Ok, included, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InputStreamReader` is not finding your "prodlist.csv" file. I suspect it should be "/prodlist.csv" as it seems you are getting this file from your `resources` folder.

In any case, you can use the full path to your file just to make sure. Add this method:

```
public Reader getFileReader(String absolutePath) {
    return new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(absolutePath)), "UTF-8");
}
```

Then call `parser.parseAll` with:

```
 List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(getFileReader("c:/path/to/prodlist.csv"));
```

Comment: Hi, I am now only getting one error, and that is: `Cannot resolve symbol 'absolutePath'`. Also, should getFileReader actually be getReader instead, it seems I had to change it to that? Also, I have the prodlist situated in the first level directory inside the Intellij folder for this project. Further, I do have the univocity-parsers-1.5.6.jar in my project library too.

Comment: The errors you are getting are from your unfamiliarity with the Java language, not the library. I suggest you to spend a little time on google going after the errors you are getting and trying to understand what is going wrong in your code. All the best.

Comment: Hi, a definite thank you for the response. I got it working. I had to put the .csv file into the src directory of the IntelliJ project. Will Univocity Parsers find the .csv if it were being run from a .jar?

Comment: It will work when reading the file from within a .jar. In this case you'll need to use something like `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream` as you did in your original question.

Comment: Hi, so the parser will definitely be able to be run from within a jar and parse a .csv file that is outside that jar? Thanks

Comment: Yes. This is all independent from the parser. All you have to do is figuring out how to open the input file.

Comment: Thanks, can Univocity Parsers allow the delimiter to be specified as a parameter? Or does it auto-detect the delimiter?

Comment: To configure the delimiter manually: `CsvParserSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter(',')`